# Jquery Declaration Differene

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already tried searching and doing google but there are no specific answer I could find
What,s the difference between declaring the jquery with document write than just have it declared without document.write
i know document.write similar to echo in php

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

and

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the only reason i can imagine any one would do the former(and i have never seen it myself) is to not bother loading the jquery library if the browser does not support javaScript

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write` to insert your scripts will block rendering of your page until that script has finished being loaded, a few of those and your page load time will suffer.